# Speed up Maven WAR resource copying

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a Maven war-project with a significant amount of small frontend-related files (>5k files). When I build my exploded WAR a huge amount of time is spent copying around these css, js and template files (> 1 minute).

Is there any sane way to improve the build speed of my maven build ? The `useCache` option is unstable. I tried symlinking the `src/main/webapp` folder but I then lose the ability to use WAR-overlays. I can't use Web-JARs either. Using `war:inplace` isn't an option too because I want to include my frontend as a war-overlay which then only gets copied to `src/main/webapp` instead of the `target` folder of the main war.

Comment: Which version of maven-war-plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using the maven-war-plugin in version 3.1.0

Comment: Have you minified your files and merged them?

Comment: What does minimizing even help ? The main war is built as an exploded folder. Compressing the overlayed war still needs unpacking thousands of files. All I get is more overhead for decompression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I did not find a real solution I have tackled this problem by configuring my tomcat to directly deploy from my maven target folder via the server.xml:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="/somepath/yourproject/target/" deployIgnore=".*(classes|generated|surefire|antrun|maven).*"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
```

This at least saves me from copying the resulting webapp files (it also allows skipping the building of the war).